# Not seeing the latest Database changes

Tags: hibernate

```
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
            for (int i = 0; i < contractorServeables.size(); i++) {
                status = UserProfileDAO.testGetJobStatusOneColumn(saveJob.getJobId());
                if ("accepted".equals(status) || "canceled".equals(status)) {
                    latch.countDown();
                    break;
                }
                MessagingFCM.sendMessageToDevice("distance", "body", contractorIdToken);
                try {
                    System.out.println("waiting");
                    latch.await(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    System.out.println("next");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            latch.countDown();
```

So I am looping over an array and I send a push notification and then I wait for 30 seconds to see if I have gotten a response from the push notification. To test this, I call my web service from Postman and after I've gotten a notification, I manually update the database field to "accepted". But I do not see the change reflect here.

```
status = UserProfileDAO.testGetJobStatusOneColumn(saveJob.getJobId());
```

This line should update the status from the database but the status does not changes from the original value. I am not sure if there is some kind of thread issue here, I can run my query and I see the value has been changed in the database, but the `status` always stays at its original value what it started with. This is struts2 & Hibernate. `testGetJobStatusOneColumn` Method is below:

```
public static String testGetJobStatusOneColumn(String jobId) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        String hql = "select status from JobBoard where jobId = :jobId";
        String t = (String) session.createQuery(hql).setString("jobId", "2").uniqueResult();
        System.out.println("JobBoard: " + t.toString());
        session.close();
        return t;
    }
```

Comment: So where exactly are you updating the database? Are you sure that the transaction is getting committed?

Comment: No code is availablabe.

Comment: @mick I think it is smwhere in the ui generated by struts.

Comment: I have put the code.
I'm updating the database manually to test it.

Comment: Yes, the transaction is getting committed because I am doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, I was not using correct dependency, make sure it is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
```